# Copy row values to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel

I seem to have a mental block right now. What I am trying to do is have VBA that copies a row, e.g., A2:H2 (values only is a must) into another worksheet once a specific value is added to column E. The functionality my code is currently lacking right now is copying values only for the row range into the other sheet.

Not sure what else to do. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = 5 And Target.Cells.Count = 1 Then
        If LCase(Target.Value) = "worker" Then
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Copy Sheets("worker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Delete
            End With
        ElseIf LCase(Target.Value) = "worker2" Then
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Copy Sheets("worker2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Delete
            End With
        ElseIf LCase(Target.Value) = "worker3" Then
            With Target.EntireRow
                .Copy Sheets("worker3").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
                .Delete
            End With
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use offset and resize to get a range in the row

```
With Target
   .Offset(, -4).Resize(1, 8).Copy  
   Sheets("worker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
   .EntireRow.Delete
End With
```

Note:

1) We are now working with Target not Target.EntireRow

2) `.Offset(, -4).Resize(1, 8)` is "A:H" where column E is target column

Comment: That seems to be giving me a 1004 error, using code:   

`code`
.Copy Sheets("worker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(, -4).Resize(1, 8)
`code`

Comment: Is that what I wrote above? Lol. No.  Take a look at edit

Comment: Gotcha. This is great! Is there any way to change this to copy over values only?

Comment: Yes. Split the copy over two lines such that first line is copy and second line is paste as values to destination. I will update.

Comment: Awesome. Now, the final piece is deleting the original row. I tried adding .Delete in the next line but it doesn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Target.EntireRow.Delete so just EntireRow.Delete see edit

Comment: You are amazing. Thank you!